# hive sql - how to select the first n elements in hive array column and return the selected array

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql

Please consider a hive table - Table as mentioned below.

```
user_id  interest_array
tom      [a,b,c,d,g,w]
bob      [e,d,s,d,g,w,s]
cat      [a]
harry    []
peter    NULL
```

I want to select the first 3 elements by sequence in 'interest_array' per row and return it as a array,  the outout to be like below

```
user_id  output_array
tom      [a,b,c]
bob      [e,d,s]
cat      [a]
harry    []
peter    NULL
```

PS: the last two rows are not important, they are just corner case, I can just set them null if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Simple method**, but it will not work correctly if initial array can contain less elements ( result array will contain NULLs ).

```
 with mydata as(
    select array('a','b','c','d','g','w') as original_array
    )
    
    select original_array, array(original_array[0], original_array[1], original_array[2]) as first_3_array
    from mydata
```

Result:

```
original_array              first_3_array
["a","b","c","d","g","w"]   ["a","b","c"]
```

**2. One more method using explode, works correctly with any arrays:**

Explode array using posexplode, filter position<=2, collect array again:

```
with mydata as(
select array('a','b','c','d','g','w') as original_array
)

select original_array, collect_list(e.element) as first_3_array
from mydata
     lateral view outer posexplode(original_array) e as pos, element
where pos<=2
group by original_array
```

Result:

```
original_array              first_3_array
["a","b","c","d","g","w"]   ["a","b","c"]
```

**3. More efficient method, without explode:** Concatenate array with comma delimiter, use regexp to extract substring with up to 3 first elements, split again:

```
with mydata as(
select array('a') as original_array
)

select original_array, split(regexp_replace(regexp_extract(concat_ws(',', original_array),
                                                           '^(([^,]*,?){1,3})',1),
                                            ',$','') --remove last delimiter
                             ,',') as first_3_array
from mydata
```

Comment: Method #3, although a bit hacky worked extremely well for me, and the working example is very useful!

A word of warning, though: I won't use method #3 when the input data is user-generated strings. See for your what happens in this case:

```with mydata as(
select array('a','a,b,c,d','c','d','e','f') as original_array
)```

Comment: @Camelhive You can use complex multi-character delimiter instead of comma in concat_ws() and in split() to reduce the probability that values can contain the same character sequence.